# Importing text into JTable - Rows aren't separating, they are just creating a single very long row. - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a JTable which is populated by various arraylists.  The issue I am having is that the data (all of it) is only going into the top row.

Am I supposed to call some sort of row delimiter or something?

The code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AllDataGUI extends JFrame{   


    private JButton saveCloseBtn = new JButton("Save Changes and Close");
    private JButton closeButton = new JButton("Exit Without Saving");
    private JFrame frame=new JFrame("Viewing All Program Details");    
    private final FileIOManagement fileManage = new FileIOManagement();    
    private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> semesterList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> moderatorList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> majorList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> programList = new ArrayList();    
    private JTable textArea = new JTable();


     public ArrayList<String> getNameList(){
         return this.nameList;
     }

     public ArrayList<String> getCourseList(){
         return this.courseList;
     }
      public ArrayList<String> getSemesterList(){
         return this.semesterList;
     }
      public ArrayList<String> getModeratorList(){
         return this.moderatorList;
     }
       public ArrayList<String> getProgramList(){
         return this.programList;
     }
        public ArrayList<String> getMajorList(){
         return this.majorList;
     }

     public void setNameList(ArrayList<String> nameList){
         this.nameList = nameList;
     }

     public void setCourseList(ArrayList<String> courseList){
         this.courseList = courseList;
     }    
      public void setSemesterList(ArrayList<String> semesterList){
         this.semesterList = semesterList;
     }    
      public void setModeratorList(ArrayList<String> moderatorList){
         this.moderatorList = moderatorList;
     }    

       public void setProgramList(ArrayList<String> programList){
         this.programList = programList;
     }    
        public void setMajorList(ArrayList<String> majorList){
         this.majorList = majorList;
     }    

     public AllDataGUI(){
         getData();
         table();
         panels();  
            }

     private void table(){

         String END_OF_LINE = "~";

         String[] colName = { "Course", "Examiner", "Moderator",
                              "Semester Available ", "Associated Programs",
                              "Associated Majors"};
            textArea.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            textArea.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            Font Tablefont = new Font("Details", Font.BOLD, 12);
            textArea.getTableHeader().setFont(Tablefont);  
            Object[][] object = new Object[100][100];
            int i = 0;                     
                    object[i][0] = fileManage.getCourseList();
                    object[i][1] = fileManage.getNameList();
                    object[i][2] = fileManage.getModeratorList();
                    object[i][3] = fileManage.getSemesterList();
                    object[i][4] = fileManage.getProgramList();
                    object[i][5] = fileManage.getMajorList();    

                    textArea = new JTable(object, colName);
                }     


      public void getData(){      
      nameList = fileManage.getNameList();
      courseList = fileManage.getCourseList();
      semesterList = fileManage.getSemesterList();
      moderatorList = fileManage.getModeratorList();
      majorList = fileManage.getMajorList();
      programList = fileManage.getProgramList();
     // textArea.(write());
  }

    private JButton getCloseButton(){
        return closeButton;
     }     




    private void panels(){        
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
          panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
          JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(15,0,10,10));
          rightPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 5, 5, 10));
          JScrollPane scrollBarForTextArea=
          new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
          JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
          panel.add(scrollBarForTextArea); 

          frame.add(panel);
          frame.getContentPane().add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
          rightPanel.add(saveCloseBtn);
          rightPanel.add(closeButton);
          closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.dispose();    
                    }
        });
          saveCloseBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //saveBtn();                
                frame.dispose();    
            }
        });
           frame.setSize(1000, 700);
           frame.setVisible(true);   
           frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
}

//    private void saveBtn(){
//        File file = null;
//        FileWriter out=null;
//        try {
//            file = new File("Course.txt");
//            out = new FileWriter(file);     
//            out.write(textArea.getText());
//            out.close();
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Successfully Updated");
//        
//  }
}
```

EDIT:  I added a loop but it is now showing nothing where the table should be.  Just blank space.

```
  private void table(){
         String[] colName = { "Course", "Examiner", "Moderator", "Semester Available ", "Associated Programs", "Associated Majors"};
         DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colName,0);
         //String[] row = new String[6];
        for(Object item: nameList){
            Object[] row = new Object[6];
         row[0] = fileManage.getCourseList();
         row[1] = fileManage.getNameList();
         row[2] = fileManage.getModeratorList();
         row[3] = fileManage.getSemesterList();
         row[4] = fileManage.getProgramList();
         row[5] = fileManage.getMajorList();
         model.addRow(row);




     }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the variable "i" always has the value of "0", so you only have a single row of data.

You can't just add an ArrayList to the TableModel. You need to add each item from the ArrayList individually to the TableModel. What you are seeing is probably the "toString()" representation of each ArrayList in a cell of the table.

If you want multiple rows then you need a loop to populate multiple rows of data. So you need to loop through all the values in your ArrayLists and increment the "i" variable for each loop.

Also, a better design is to not create a 2Dimension Array of 100 x 100. This will just create extra rows of data that contain no values. Instead you should use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add one row of data at to time to the table.

> Rows aren't separating, they are just creating a single very long row. - Java Swing

The reason you see a long row is because you define the table to contain 100 rows and 100 columns, which is not reasonable since you only have 6 columns of data. I don't know how many rows, but that is why you should use the addRow() method and not try to hard code the size of the TableModel.

The code should be something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnName, 0);
```

Then you create a loop:

```
String[] row = new String[6];
row[0] = fileManage.getNameList().get(i);
row[1] = fileManage.getCourseList().get(i);
...
model.addRow( row );
```

Comment: Creation of the loop has me scratching my head.  Sorry to ask, but how should I do it?

Comment: should I create a loop for every arraylist as there are several that are used to obtain the data?

Comment: I suggested you create a single loop (and that is what my sample code does). Of course this assumes that you have the same number of items in each ArrayList (which is the basic assumption when you use a JTable, since every row should have data for each column).

Comment: I have created a loop but now where the table should be is just blank space.

Comment: Did you create the JTable using the TableModel?

Comment: And I already told you that you can't add an ArrayList to the TableModel. I said you need to add one item at a time and the code I gave you suggestion you need to uset the `get(...)` method of the ArrayList to get each individual item.

Comment: Would I be better off using a JTextArea?

Comment: No. A JTable is designed to show row/column data. If you have never used a JTable before then read the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` for basic information. You can find a link to the tutorial by reading the JTable API.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking stupid questions, but do you mean I should write a look for each row of the table?

Comment: You already wrote the code for the loop. Now you just need to use the `ArrayList.get(...)` method every time the loop executes to add 1 item from each of the 6 ArrayLists to the row Array so you can add one row at a time to the TableModel. I gave you the example code, why are you NOT using the `get(...)` method???